# Overriding isSystemOn setting for a single page

Tags: craft3, config

I have a staging site that has the `isSystemOn` set to `false` since I don't want people to stumble upon the site and be able to view content. I would like to have **1** page still "visible" though. This URL would a simple *health check* page, that I direct a monitoring service to check on. I'm stumped at overriding a system level `isSystemOn` config setting.

Can I have `staging.example.com/my-secret-health-check-url` return a valid code of `200` so my monitoring service can correctly see that my staging site is working?

Answer (score 6):

I realized there is a simpler solution after stepping away from this issue for a bit. There is one page that still returns a 200 code on a Craft site even when the `isSystemOn` (or `isSystemLive` as of Craft 3.1) is `false`. Using the **control panel login page** as a health check url is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just have that page not be in the CMS. Create something like `web/ping.html` and point the monitoring service at that static file.

If you want it to work anyway, you could have an `offline.html` template, and you could change the status code that it returns... but that would be a little weird.

It was changed to `isSystemLive` btw... more info here: [Handling Errors Gracefully in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/handling-errors-gracefully-in-craft-cms#offline-staging-sites)

Comment: A static file wouldn't work well as a health check. We also use `/admin/login` as a health check as you have more assurance that PHP and Craft are well.

Comment: Makes sense, it's true that a static file will only tell you that the server and webserver are up and working, not that PHP and Craft are well.